# Mysql need to get one column two times from table1 and sort them by two different columns of table2

Tags: mysql, join

So here is the thing, I have two tables:

- table1 has columns `intUsersID, varUsersName`
- table2 has columns `intCouriers, intResponsible`

`intCouriers` (have some numbers of intUsersID that are Couriers), and `intResponsible` (have some numbers of intUsersID that are Responsible)

In my query I must see User Names of Couriers and of the  Responsible persons
 something like that:

```
SELECT 
    table1.varUsersName 'Couriers',
    table1.varUsersName 'Responsible'
FROM
    table1 
LEFT JOIN 
    table2 ON table2.intCouriers = table1.intUsersID
```

And then I need some how to subquery or join this "table1.varUsersName 'Responsible'", to get also 'Reponsible' persons. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Should be this

```
SELECT table1.varUsersName 'Couriers', table2.varUsersName 'Responsible'
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table3  on table1.intUsersID = table3.intCouriers
INNER JOIN table1  as Table2 on  table2.intUsersID = table3. intResponsible
```

Comment: Well, not quite it, I have much more data from 4 tables to get my full query. So it must fit to the one big query

Comment: Here I have only 2 tables

Comment: if you want obtain two value for the name related to two different column (intCouriers , intResponsile) you can use only one time the table 1 but you must use two table this table .. so you have table1 as table2

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Couriers.varUsersName as "Couriers",
       Responsible.varUsersName as "Responsible"
FROM   `table2` t2
   LEFT JOIN table1 Couriers on Couriers.intUsersID = t2.intCouriers
   LEFT JOIN table1 Responsible on Responsible.intUsersID = t2.intResponsible
```